# Can i make a website without an user login

Tags: post, authentication, html, login-control

I'm planning to make a simple one page or two page website on travel experience. Guests can sent me those details by form  and I can post it on website.

Comment: If you haven't lost a trust on world. then you must go without user login else make it proper authentication

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, yes you can.

From what I understand you want any visitor to your site to be able to type up a travel experience on the site, submit it, you then moderate and check it, and decide to publish it or not.

As much as that describes a "simple one or two page website", there is a lot that needs to happen for you to accomplish that:

1. You will need a database to store the user submissions in;
2. You probably want some kind of protection mechanism so that a malicious user or bot cannot just submit millions of rubbish entries;
3. You will want to send commands to your database in a way that prevents "SQL Injection" whereby a user can hide malicious actions (like deleting all your data in the database) inside his submission.

I can carry on, but I think you get the point: what you want to do is a simple technical exercise for someone who already knows how to build dynamic websites, but quite a challenge for someone with little or no experience.

That does not mean that it won't be a worthwhile exercise and a most valuable learning experience, but it won't be a quick couple of days' work for someone without the experience and knowledge.

There are tons of free resources on the web that you can use to learn to do exactly what you envision, so I encourage you to go for it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support. I understood everything you explained. I'm before this website for month or more getting lessons from many. Anyways that's a lot

Answer (score 1):

They are no need of the user login to send Posts to you. You can simply design a `Submit Post` page and get the Posts under your view. After that you can Publish or reject the submitted posts.
But there are some problems,

- You can not verify the users who are submitting the posts
- Accuracy    of the posts will be reduce due to unauthorized requests.

Comment: Thanks for your support